# Telegram does not escape some markdown characters

Tags: markdown, telegram-bot

Telegram does not escape some markdown characters, for example:

- This works fine

  _test\_test_
- But this return parse error

  *test\*test*

What I do wrong?

Comment: Have you faced the similar issue for `MarkdownV2` https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style

Answer (score 35):

```
String escapedMsg = toEscapeMsg
    .replace("_", "\\_")
    .replace("*", "\\*")
    .replace("[", "\\[")
    .replace("`", "\\`");
```

Do not escape `]` character. If `[` is escaped, `]` is treated like a normal character.

Comment: This works fine for me with the current Telegram version 1.5.6

Comment: This fails on text like "test_test". E.g. it will produce message "test\\_test".

Comment: For escaping more than one character, it'd be best to use regular expressions with the global flag.

Comment: This fixed it for me! Cheers!

Comment: When escaping multiple dots `.`  try `.replace(/\./g, "\\.")` worked for me

Comment: There are a lot more symbols to replace. Try to send whole ASCII symbols to test. Its better to use ParseMode.HTML if you can't control message content

Answer (score 11):

The only workaround is to use `HTML` in the `parse_mode`

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style

Comment: So sad but true!

Comment: still need replace "<" with "&lt;" because it will be read as tag start and probably unrecognized

Answer (score 11):

according to telegram API

`` In all other places characters '_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')', '~', '`', '>', '#', '+', '-', '=', '|', '{', '}', '.', '!' must be escaped with the preceding character '\'. ``

so here is function I've used

```
text
  .replace(/\_/g, '\\_')
  .replace(/\*/g, '\\*')
  .replace(/\[/g, '\\[')
  .replace(/\]/g, '\\]')
  .replace(/\(/g, '\\(')
  .replace(/\)/g, '\\)')
  .replace(/\~/g, '\\~')
  .replace(/\`/g, '\\`')
  .replace(/\>/g, '\\>')
  .replace(/\#/g, '\\#')
  .replace(/\+/g, '\\+')
  .replace(/\-/g, '\\-')
  .replace(/\=/g, '\\=')
  .replace(/\|/g, '\\|')
  .replace(/\{/g, '\\{')
  .replace(/\}/g, '\\}')
  .replace(/\./g, '\\.')
  .replace(/\!/g, '\\!')
```

But keep in mind, this means if you mean to use ***some text*** as bold text this script will render *some text* instead without applying the bold effect

Comment: Yeah, use a capture group instead lol `text.replace(/([|{\[\]*_~}+)`(#>!=\-.])/gm, '\\$1');`

Comment: I have ended up using this line in python:
`text = re.sub(r'[_*[\]()~>#\+\-=|{}.!]', lambda x: '\\' + x.group(), text)`

Answer (score 8):

Actually both are getting error.

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "error_code": 400,
  "description": "Bad Request: Can't parse message text: Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 11"
}
```

sounds like Telegram doesn't support escape characters for markdown, so i suggest you to use HTML instead:
`<b>test*test</b>`

Comment: This display bold string `test\test` without '\*'. But I want display bold `test*test`...

Comment: Yes you're right. Telegram has some issues in escape characters. i've edited my answer and suggested another way. Maybe report this bug to telegram bot support.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `'\\'` to escape markup tokens `` *_[` ``, i.e. send this instead:

`*test\\*test*`

Comment: @Oleg, you are wrong. Have you tried to send this sequence directly in Insomnia or other REST tool, or from your code?  If your language use `\` as escape characher you have to double it.

Comment: It doesn't relate on language, because Telegram itself doesn't support this feature. For testing I've used Postman. Furthermore you can find in Telegram documentation that they provide some of HTML entities (which is the same as escaping) https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style

Answer (score 4):

Ironically if the `parse_mode` argument is set to `markdown` instead of using the `ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2` constant in the `python` without escaping any character `send_message` function works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use [MarkdownV2](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style).

```
{
    "chat_id": telegram_chat_id,
    "parse_mode": "MarkdownV2",
    "text": "*test\*test*"
}
```

Just escape these characters:

'_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')', '~', '`', '>', '#', '+', '-', '=', '|', '{', '}', '.', '!'

and telegram will handle the rest.

Answer (score 2):

```
function escapeMarkdown(text) {
    return text.replace(/[_*[\]()~`>#\+\-=|{}.!]/g, '\\$&'); 
}
```

// Example usage

```
const originalText = '_*Hello [World]*~';
const escapedText = escapeMarkdown(originalText);
console.log(escapedText); // Result: '\\_\\*Hello \\[World\\]\\*\\~'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ $json.content.replace(/_|[*`~>#+=|{}()\\.!-]/g, "\\$&") }}
```

This version helped to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

pdenti's answer only replaces *the first* character found in the message. Use regular expressions with the global tag to replace all of them.

```
String escapedMsg = toEscapeMsg
    .replace(/_/g, "\\_")
    .replace(/\*/g, "\\*")
    .replace(/\[/g, "\\[")
    .replace(/`/g, "\\`");
```

Comment: that is not correct. Every occurrence gets replaced, as from javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-